# Factory and generics

Tags: java, generics

I have the following classes:

```
public interface IDataSource<T> {
  public List<T> getData(int numberOfEntries);
}

public class MyDataSource implements IDataSource<MyData> {
  public List<MyData> getData(int numberOfEntries) {
    ...
  }
}

public class MyOtherDataSource implements IDataSource<MyOtherData> {
  public List<MyOtherData> getData(int numberOfEntries) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I would like to use a factory that return the correct implementation based on the data type. I wrote the following but I get "Unchecked cast" warnings:

```
public static <T> IDataSource<T> getDataSource(Class<T> dataType) {
    if (dataType.equals(MyData.class)) {
        return (IDataSource<T>) new MyDataSource();
    } else if (dataType.equals(MyOtherData.class)) {
        return (IDataSource<T>) new MyOtherDataSource();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Am I doing it wrong? What can I do to get rid of the warnings?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but you can safely use `==` for `Class`es instead of `equals`.

Answer (score 5):

I am not aware of any way to get rid of those warnings without `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

You are passing in a `Class` object so `T` can be captured.  But you are forced to check the `Class` at runtime to determine which `IDataSource<T>` to return.  At this time, type erasure has long since occurred.

At compile time, Java can't be sure of type safety.  It can't guarantee that the `T` in the `Class` at runtime would be the same `T` in the `IDataSource<T>` returned, so it produces the warning.

This looks like one of those times when you're forced to annotate the method with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to remove the warning.  That warning is there for a reason, so it is up to you to provide and ensure type safety.  As written, it looks like you have provided type safety.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> IDataSource<T> getDataSource(Class<T> dataType) {
```

Answer (score 4):

You're doing it right, and you should simply suppress the warnings. Factories are one of the tricky areas in generics where you really do need to manually cast to a generic type, and you have to ensure via whatever means that the returned value matches the `Class<T>` you pass in. For example, in this case you're hard-coding a couple of `IDataSource` implementations, so I would recommend writing unit tests that verify that the types are correct so that if the `MyData` implementation changes in an incompatible way, you'll get an error on build.

Just annotate the `getDataSource` method with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, and it's always a good idea to add an explanatory comment when suppressing warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Generics are for compile-time type safety. They can't be used for runtime type determination like that. To get rid of the warning, you can do something like `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` or use the `-Xlint:-unchecked` compiler flag, as described in the ["Raw Types" part of the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have answered the problem as you posed it. But I'd like to take a step back to understand what you're trying to accomplish with this factory method. This factory basically provides a map of data types to `IDataSource` parameters. [Dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) might be a more appropriate pattern since this is a small well-known set of data types and implementations (as indicated by your example).

Let's say you want to store all `Widgets` in Mongo but all `Gadgets` in Mysql, you might have two classes: a `MongoWidgetDataSource` that implements `IDataSource<Widget>` and a `MysqlGadgetDataSource` that implements `IDataSource<Gadget>`.

Instead of hardcoding a factory method call like `MyFactory.getDataSource(Widget.class)` inside a data consumer, I would inject the appropriate `IDataSource` dependency. We might have `MyService` that does something with widgets (stored in mongo). Using a factory as you proposed would look like this:

```
public class MyService {
  public void doSomething() {
    String value = MyFactory.getDataSource(Widget.class).getSomething();
    // do something with data returned from the source
  }
}
```

Instead, you should inject the appropriate data source as a constructor arg into the service:

```
public class MyService {
  private final IDataSource<Widget> widgetDataSource;

  public MyService(IDataSource<Widget> widgetDataSource) {
    this.widgetDataSource = widgetDataSource;
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    String value = widgetDataSource.getSomething();
    // now do something with data returned from the source
  }
}
```

This has the added benefit of making your code more reusable and easier to unit test (mock dependencies).

Then, where you instantiate `MyService`, you can also wire up your data sources. Many projects use a dependency injection framework (like [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)) to make this easier, but its not a strict requirement. Personally, though, I never work on a project of any real size or duration without one.

If you don't use an DI framework, you just instantiate the dependencies when you create the calling service:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IDataSource<Widget> widgetDataSource = new MongoWidgetDataSource();
    IDataSource<Gadget> gadgetDataSource = new MysqlGadgetDataSource();
    MyService service = new MyService(widgetDataSource, gadgetDataSource);
    service.doSomething();
}
```

In Guice, you would wire up these data sources like this:

```
public class DataSourceModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(new TypeLiteral<IDataSource<Widget>>() {}).to(MongoWidgetDataSource.class);
    bind(new TypeLiteral<IDataSource<Gadget>>() {}).to(MysqlGadgetDataSource.class);
  }
}
```

Dependency inversion is a bit of a different way to think about the problem, but it can lead to a much more decoupled, reusable and testable code base.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
public static <T> IDataSource<T> getDataSource(MyData dataType) {
  System.out.println("Make MyDataSource");
  return (IDataSource<T>) new MyDataSource();
}

public static <T> IDataSource<T> getDataSource(MyOtherData dataType) {
  System.out.println("Make MyOtherDataSource");
  return (IDataSource<T>) new MyOtherDataSource();
}

public void test() {
  IDataSource<MyData> myDataSource = getDataSource((MyData) null);
  IDataSource<MyOtherData> myOtherDataSource = getDataSource((MyOtherData) null);
}
```

You may prefer to create empty archetypes rather than cast `null` like I have but I think this is a viable technique.