# Java Factory of Generic Classes

Tags: java, generics, reflection, types, factory-pattern

This question is similar to [Factory and generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460325/factory-and-generics), and may have the same answer, but it is different. I have a generic base class that will be extended by classes in a completely separate JAR. Said JAR should be able to be dropped in and replaced without changing any other code (code is executed on command).

The base class:

```
public abstract class ThingBase<A> {

    public abstract A doThing();

    public abstract Thing getThingType();

    // This might be the wrong way to do this, and I elaborate below.
    public final SortedMap<Long, A> getCollectionContainer() {
        return new TreeMap<Long, A>();
    }

}
```

I have an enum that I will be creating different thing extensions for each entry.

```
public enum Thing { T1, T2, T3 }
```

The factory creating such objects:

```
public class ThingFactory {
    private static final Map<Thing, Class<? extends ThingInterface<?>>> thingMap;

    static{//populate map by finding all extensions of base class}

    public static ThingBase<?> getThing(Thing thing) {
        try {
            Class<? extends ThingBase<?>> thingImpl = thingMap.get(thing);
            if (thingImpl != null) {
                return thingImpl.newInstance();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is with the unchecked and raw type warnings in the below code (note not above, above code compiles just fine). In the following usage, the code executes successfully, but I get unchecked type warnings.

```
public class ThingAccumulator {
    // Raw Type
    private final ThingBase myThing;

    // Raw Type
    private SortedMap myMap;

    public ThingAccumulator(Thing thing) {
        myThing = ThingFactory.getThing(thing);
        myMap = myThing.getCollectionData();
        //Type safety: The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type Map. References to generic type Map<K,V> should be parameterized
        myMap.put(System.currentTimeMillis(), myThing.doThing());
    }
}
```

Putting < ? > on both ThingBase and < Long, ?> on SortedMap fields complains about the ?s are different:

The method put(Long, capture#17-of ?) in the type Map is not applicable for the arguments (long, capture#18-of ?)

Now the major issue here seems to be that the compiler cannot assume the ? and ? are the same, which is fair, but the only solution I have come up with so far is to put the type in the holding class, which isnt an option because only the implementation knows the data type :/

Does anyone have ANY idea on how to rid of these warnings? Is there a better way to be doing this?

Thanks,

SDY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a generic type parameter to `ThingAccumulator`, use that to move things around so that the only code Java complains about is one simple line that you can prove truly is type-safe, then suppress that warning because you know it is not a problem.

Giving a type parameter to `ThingAccumulator` lets its fields be type checked when used together. You can push the question of "but what's the type?" outside of the constructor by taking a `ThingBase<A>` instance as the parameter instead of a `Thing` enum value. Then, a static factory method can handle the object construction:

```java
public class ThingAccumulator<A> {
    private final ThingBase<A> myThing;

    private SortedMap<Long, A> myMap;

    public static ThingAccumulator<?> create(Thing thing) {
        return new ThingAccumulator(ThingFactory.getThing(thing));
    }

    protected ThingAccumulator(ThingBase<A> thing) {
        myThing = thing;
        myMap = myThing.getCollectionData();
        myMap.put(System.currentTimeMillis(), myThing.doThing());
    }
}
```

I wish Java would like the `create()` function. The logic could go something like this:

- `ThingFactory.getThing()` returns a `ThingBase<?>`. That's like a `ThingBase<X>` for some unknown `X`. Just because we don't know it doesn't mean it doesn't exist.
- `new ThingAccumulator()` can take a `ThingBase<X>`, for any `X`, and return a `ThingAccumulator<X>`.
- Now we have a `ThingAccumulator<?>` — an instance with an unknown type parameter. Type safety hasn't been broken.

However, Java doesn't like it (at least in my version of Java 1.7.0). But if *we* like it, we can suppress the warning:

```java
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static ThingAccumulator<?> create(Thing thing) {
        return new ThingAccumulator(ThingFactory.getThing(thing));
    }
```

And because all the rest of the code (so far…) is type-safe, no more warnings.

Comment: I get a raw types warning on the creating of ThingAccumulator here, but I am basically going to just suppress the warnings. Moving the type parameter up a class for some reason did not really occur to me. Amazing how simple the solutions are in software despite staring at a loss for hours.